# <span class="wmi-callto">...</span> in a email

Tags: email, html, email-client

What is <span class="wmi-callto">...</span> in a email?

We have created a email without "wmi-callto" using our server. But our customer sent us an erroneous email with <span class="wmi-callto">...</span> in it, as a demonstration that our software is wrong.

I am assigned to investigate this case. Please help. What to say to the customer?

Comment: so, essentially you are getting paid for not knowing what you are doing in your job?

Answer (score 1):

If you have verified that the email is sent without such markup (better double-check it... test it by sending to your test address and carefully checking the email message in raw HTML format), the apparent answer is that the user’s email client is adding it. It could be some code intended to cleverly recognize phone numbers from message content and marking them up that way, in order to let the user call those numbers. It could also be some intermediary software that has intercepted the message.